# Using jQuery, JSON and AJAX,codeigniter to populate a submenu drop down

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I have created a form with menu and submenu. I load the menu dropdown from database but i am facing the problem to load submenu from database using ajax,json and codeigniter pls solve my issue.. thanks in advance...

This is My view coding

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frm_submenu">
               <div class="form-group">
               <label for="menu">Select Menu</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="selectmenuid">
                    <option value="">-- Select Menu --</option>
                    <?php foreach($showData as $show):?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $show->menu_id?>"><?php echo $show->menu_name?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>
                </div>
               <div class="form-group">
               <label for="menu">Select Sub Menu</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="selectsubmenu">

                    </select>
               </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="imagetitle">Image Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imagetitle" id="imagetitle" placeholder="Enter Image Title" required="required">
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                Browse <input type="file" style="display: none;">
              </label>
              </div>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
           </form>
```

This is my ajax and jquery and json coding

```
$( "#selectmenuid" ).change(function() {
       var id = $('#selectmenuid').val();
          populate_submenu(id);
       });

function populate_submenu(id){
     $('#selectsubmenu').empty();
     $('#selectsubmenu').append("<option>Loading ....</option>");
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "<?php echo site_url('Admin_Creator/populate_submenu')?>/"+id,
         contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
         dataType:'json',
         success:function(data){
         $('#selectsubmenu').empty();
         $('#selectsubmenu').append("<option>Select Sub Menu</option>");
         $.each(data,function(i,name){
             $('#selectsubmenu').append('<option value="'+data[i].submenu_id+'"'+data[name].submenu_name+'</option>');
         });
       }
     });
}
```

This is my controller coding

```
public function populate_submenu($id){
        $smid=$id;
        $data['query']= $this->db->select("select * from submenu where menu_id='$smid'");
        echo json_encode($data);        

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had an error when structuring your `item` html with appends. Use this instead:

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    $('#selectsubmenu').append('<option value="'+value.submenu_id+'">'+value.submenu_name+'</option>');
});
```

Comment: problem is solved: success: function(data) {
                   $('select#selectsubmenu').html('<option>--Select Sub Menu--</option>');
                  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                  {
                  
                    $("<option />").val(data[i].submenu_id)
                                   .text(data[i].submenu_name)
                                   .appendTo($('select#selectsubmenu'));
                  }
                 }

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems at a first view. First your `$smid` variable should be in double quotes or escaped corespondingly. Variables in single quotes are treated as they look so your php code should look like this:

```
public function populate_submenu($id){
        $smid=$id;
        $data['query']= $this->db->select('select * from submenu where menu_id="$smid"');
        echo json_encode($data);        

 }
```

In your JS code you are not closing the `>` from the starting open `<option>` tag in the `each()` method and getting the `submenu_name` wrong, you should get it by the index, so:

```
$('#selectsubmenu').append('<option value="' + data[i].submenu_id + '"' + data[name].submenu_name + '</option>');
```

should be:

```
$('#selectsubmenu').append('<option value="' + data[i].submenu_id + '">' + data[i].submenu_name + '</option>');
```

The code should be:

```
$("#selectmenuid").change(function() {
  var id = $('#selectmenuid').val();
  populate_submenu(id);
});

function populate_submenu(id) {
  $('#selectsubmenu').empty();
  $('#selectsubmenu').append("<option>Loading ....</option>");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('Admin_Creator/populate_submenu')?>/" + id,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#selectsubmenu').empty();
      $('#selectsubmenu').append("<option>Select Sub Menu</option>");
      $.each(data, function(i, name) {
        $('#selectsubmenu').append('<option value="' + data[i].submenu_id + '">' + data[i].submenu_name + '</option>');
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I check the both above code.. when i click the menu name its loading but in sub menu its showing like undefined.

Comment: @AntoAlexander, I will have to see the JSON in `data` so I can help. What output do you get in the console if you do a `console.log(data);` on AJAX success?

Comment: @ lonut hi ,On ajax success area i put console.log(data); after that i load my page and select the menu after that i check it in console its showing XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/creator/Admin_Creator/populate_submenu/3". my menu id only passing successfully but there is no result come for submenu... Pls solve this thanks in advance

Comment: So when you select something on `#selectsubmenu`  you don't get the JSON on success? What's on the localhost link `localhost/creator/Admin_Creator/populate_submenu/3`? Only you can access that. Sorry, but I won't be able to determine the problem if you don't help me here. I need to see the JSON. If you can't find it in the console when you do `console.log(data)` that means that there is your problem, the data is not passing through.

Comment: yes you are correct.. But i am a newer in this concept i dont know how to get this in to success page...

Comment: @AntoAlexander, is there any output when you enter on this link `localhost/creator/Admin_Creator/populate_submenu/3` ? You have to `echo` the encoded json there. If there is nothing on this link there is the problem. I can't actually help you out in this case without seeing the whole code.

Comment: @lunut thank you for your support . That problem is solved... I like to keep and touche with you this is my facebook page.. https://www.facebook.com/anto.alexander.07  . will you share your fb also...